# Error on assertion - Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.List

Tags: karate

Getting an error while making an assertion

`field1` is value from DB and I want to match them with `field2` (value from response xml)

```
* def field1 = get TABLE[*].COLUMN
```

Field2 is result of below operation

```
* def field2 = get Response SOME_XML_XPATH
```

it may contains single value of list of value like
`field2 = 19.2` or `field2 = ["188.3","281.11"]`

Issue is when I try to compare both fields when they are list like
`field1 = [1850, 700, 30] field2 = ["1850.0","30.0","700.0"]`
To resolve this, I used below code,

```
* def field1 = [1850, 700, 30]
* def field2 = ["1850.0","30.0","700.0"]
* def field3 = karate.map(field2, function(x){ return ~~x })
* match field1 contains only field3
```

This works fine however, When `field2` is single value, and I want to match it with `field1`, i get below error

> Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.List

Comment: voting to close as too broad. definitely not a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs. There is something called `contains`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#match-contains

```
* def field1 = [1850, 700, 30]
* def field2 = "30.0"
* def field2 = ~~field2
* match field1 contains field2
```

Comment: Let me try to reiterate my issue
Objective – Validate all fields value from Response xml with the values from Database for same fields. Example
field1_db is value from DB and i want to match them with field1_response(value from response xml)
* def field1_db = get TABLE[*].COLUMN

Field1_response is result of below operation
* def field1_response = karate.get(‘$Response/Field_XML_XPATH’)

Comment: Issue – Data types changes(Integer string) when field contains single value or multiple value. 
Consider example from below site
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp
Considering this as a Response XML, I want to match validate Price field from DB and Response.

Comment: Price field is list of 4 values[30,29.99,49.99,39.95]. In other cases, Response may contain 1 value, lets say 30.
In my case, when field contains list of value and its datatype is String, it will change to integer when it contains single value or vice-a-versa and it causes a problem on assertion.
Below is list of my fields and their return data type when field is single/multie value
How do I handle this in Karate?

Comment: @Karate_user you can comment all you want but unless your question is clear, no one can help you. all the best :)